# Swagger maven build - NTLM issue while downloading swagger-ui/archive/master.tar.gz

Tags: proxy, ntlm, swagger, swagger-maven-plugin

I am trying to get hands on Swagger and attempted to download and run few sample on my machine, stumbled upon following error and not able to proceed. Any help would really be appreciated.

I cloned the git code from https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-samples.git

and on command prompt I tried `mvn package tomcat6:run`

Note that I am behind proxy and have configured maven settings.xml as guided at https://maven.apache.org/settings.html#Proxies

**ERROR:**
 [INFO] --- download-maven-plugin:1.2.1:wget (swagger-ui) @ swagger-java-cxf-sample ---
Downloading: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/archive/master.tar.gz
Jun 19, 2015 12:20:42 PM org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.client.protocol.RequestAuthenticationBase process
WARNING: NTLM authentication error: Credentials cannot be used for NTLM authentication: org.apache.maven.wagon.providers.http.httpclient.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials
org.apache.maven.wagon.authorization.AuthorizationException: Not authorized by proxy , ReasonPhrase:Proxy Authentication Required.
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.shared.http4.AbstractHttpClientWagon.fillInputData(AbstractHttpClientWagon.java:936)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getInputStream(StreamWagon.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.getIfNewer(StreamWagon.java:88)
        at org.apache.maven.wagon.StreamWagon.get(StreamWagon.java:61)
        at com.googlecode.WGet.doGet(WGet.java:293)
        at com.googlecode.WGet.execute(WGet.java:223)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)

Answer (score 1):

The issue basically occurs when you are accessing the maven repository from behind office proxy.  To resolve this issue, you need to prefix prefix the user names in proxy credential as well as all server tags something like below.

```
<server>
    <id>isb-libs-dev</id>
    <username><internal.java.corp>\username</username>
    <password>password</password>
</server>
```